# How to login with windows Active Directory in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, active-directory

I am creating a project in which there is requirement for implementing windows Active Directory login system in MVC Application. I have tried many things from google but I'm struggling to find a way of doing this.

Actually, I want to know the process from scratch.

Does anyone have any insight or a link to a good explanation? Google has not brought up much help.

This is my `web.config` file:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/User/LoginUser" timeout="45" 
           slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" />
  </authentication>
  <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
           connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"  />            
    </providers>
  </membership>

<connectionStrings>
      <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://domain:389/DC=domain,DC=Local" />
<connectionStrings>
```

My controller is below. In this there is an error showing LDAP connection string does not represent valid LDAP adspath.

```cs
public ActionResult LoginUser()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LoginUser(LoginUser login, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MembershipProvider domainProvider = Membership.Providers["ADMembershipProvider"];
        if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(login.UserName, login.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.UserName,true);
            if(Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Service");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect");
    }

    return View(login);
}
```

This is my login view:

```xml
<div class="row mt-5 ">
        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3 bodyColor ">
            <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
                <div style="max-width: 400px;">
                    <br />
                    <h2>
                        Login
                    </h2>
                    <br />
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:325px;" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "textRed" })

                    <br />

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:325px;", type = "password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "textRed" })

                    <br />
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RememberMe)
                    
                    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]" />
                    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" style="width:90px;" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" style="width:90px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="dvMessage" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Error!</strong>
                <span>@ViewBag.Message</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
```

Comment: Create empty project -> Select your project in `Solution Explorer` window -> In `Properties` window set `Windows Authentication` = `Enabled` and `Anonymous Authentication` = `Disabled` -> Run your project -> Inside your controller you can get current user principal with `this.User`

Comment: Thanks for answer.I have done this, but I am not getting the login widow to login with some other user. It is only logon with current user.

Comment: Then you on a right path. Can you provide full exception message? Also, after a little googling, I found some posts, where there was extra `connectionUsername` and `connectionPassword` attributes in `<add name="ADMembershipProvider" … /> ` tag, have you try them?

Comment: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'The specified connection string does not represent a valid LDAP adspath. This is the error that I get. I tried many ways of getting correct LDAP but couldn't get one. Do u know the correct way of writing LDAP connection string? ..... or how to access active directory?